# In-App Billing V3 - Purchase an Object that expires after 3 months - Android

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I must implement in an Android App the purchase of an item that expires after 3 months.

I read on the developer guide that I should use "unmanaged" products, but I also read that in V3 Version of the API this object is handle as a managed product.

The question is the following, after the users buy an unmanaged object how can I manage the expiration?
For example when the period will expire, the user can purchase another time the same product if he want?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using an online database for your app?

If true, I think that the best way to do it is generating the end date when item is purchased and saving it in an online database. Then you have to check if end date is not past regularly in your app (for example every time that user start app,...).

This works for me, but in my case app connects regularly to a online database to work.

Other methods, like save end date in local storage can be easy hacked.

Comment: yes I have a backend for my app, but in this manner when the product expires the user can't buy it again.

Comment: The thing that I do is create an "Unamanaged Product" on Google Play (every user can buy it all times that he want) and every time that he buy it I added the desired time (3 months in your case) to the end_date. If an user buy it two consecutive times, the end_date will be 6 months later... I hope that this can help you.